# Query a table for duplicate entries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I currently use this query to make a tag cloud with the most popular search terms:

```
$query = "SELECT search_time
               , search_keywords
          FROM phpbb_popsearch2
          ORDER BY search_time DESC
          LIMIT 120";
```

I want to remove search terms that aren't used often enough to be in the tag cloud. So i would like to restrict the queries only to the `search_keywords` that appears at least **10** times in the `phpbb_popsearch2`.

What is the best way to do that without adding a second query every time the first one is executed?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can select/group your search_keywords by having # of entries count >= 10.

```
SELECT
        search_keywords
    FROM
        phpbb_popsearch2
    GROUP BY
        search_keywords
    HAVING 
        COUNT(*) >= 10
```

Comment: What about the `search_time` column?

Comment: Simply adding search_time to the SELECT clause would return search_time entries that have search_keywords >= 10.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a subquery with a `having` clause:

```
SELECT   search_time, search_keywords 
FROM     phpbb_popsearch2 
WHERE    search_keywords IN (SELECT   search_keywords
                             FROM     phpbb_popsearch2 
                             GROUP BY search_keywords
                             HAVING   COUNT(*) >= 10)
ORDER BY search_time DESC 
LIMIT    120
```

Comment: the query overloads my server, result in huge cpu load spike and the page returns 500 internal server error :(